# 404 on HTTP get request sent from payment gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, spree

Whenever my website receives a get request from the payment gateway, it redirects to 404 pages instead of passing gateway response to the controller. 
Gateway request looks like this: https://domain/callback?data=encrypted-string
When I copy and paste the same link into browser, everything works fine.
This behavior is present only on the production server where SSL encryption is on. In my local test environment, everything works as expected. 
Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you checked that they are hitting the `https` link rather than `http` it might not get redirected

Comment: Yes, they provide debugging info with the link and it seems ok. When I copy it to the browser, it returns correct response, but when I press "retry" button on the debugging console, the 404 page is being returned.

Comment: Have you got a screenshot of this error, blur the your code specific parts. I would like to know which provider you are on though

Comment: Also will be great to look logs (rails or nginx) for this request. And are you sure that payment gateway use `GET` not `POST` request?

Comment: I had accidentally selected "use POST method" in the console. Thank you and sorry for wasting your time.